# static linking c++ opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11

I want to make static linking with library OpenCV, but I have some problems.
I use Linux (Ubuntu), IDE Clion, cmake and library OpenCV.

When I run project I get error:

```
[50%] Linking CXX executable OpenCVLinkingStatic /usr/bin/ld:
attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.9'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/OpenCVLinkingStatic.dir/build.make:112: recipe for target 'OpenCVLinkingStatic' failed
make[3]: *** [OpenCVLinkingStatic] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/OpenCVLinkingStatic.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/OpenCVLinkingStatic.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/OpenCVLinkingStatic.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/OpenCVLinkingStatic.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'OpenCVLinkingStatic' failed
make: *** [OpenCVLinkingStatic] Error 2
```

CMakeListst.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(OpenCVLinkingStatic)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(OpenCVLinkingStatic main.cpp)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(OpenCVLinkingStatic ${OpenCV_LIBS} "-static")
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   Mat image = imread("/opt/my.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
   namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
   imshow("Display window", image);
   waitKey(0);

   return 0;
}
```

I installed openCV library via command "sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev" in terminal.

I have all needed labraries with expansion ".a":

```
libopencv_core.a
libopencv_highgui.a
libopencv_video.a
libopencv_objdetect.a
```

They are located in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/".

When I try execute command:

```
"gcc -static -std=c++11 main.cpp
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.a 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.a 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.a 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.a 
-lm -lpthread -lstdc++ -o MyBinary".
```

I get many lines containing each time typical errors:

```
"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): In function
icvCloseFile(CvFileStorage*) :
(.text._ZL12icvCloseFileP13CvFileStorage+0x52): undefined reference to  gzclose 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): In function  icvEof(CvFileStorage*) :
(.text._ZL6icvEofP13CvFileStorage+0x42): undefined reference to  gzeof...
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.a(window_gtk.cpp.o): In function
cvImageWidget_class_init(_CvImageWidgetClass*) :
(.text._ZL24cvImageWidget_class_initP19_CvImageWidgetClass+0xa): undefined reference to  gtk_widget_get_type 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.a(window_gtk.cpp.o): In function  cvImageWidget_class_init(_CvImageWidgetClass*) :
(.text._ZL24cvImageWidget_class_initP19_CvImageWidgetClass+0x15): undefined reference to  gtk_type_class 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.a(window_gtk.cpp.o): In function  cvImageWidget_class_init(_CvImageWidgetClass*) 
(.text._ZL24cvImageWidget_class_initP19_CvImageWidgetClass+0x20): undefined
reference to  g_type_check_class_cast 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"
```

Earlier I built openCV via Sources and endicated parameter "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF".
But it didn't work so, however I had all libraries with expansion ".a".
I got errors "indefined cv::imread" and other like this.
If I use dynamic linking all work correctly.
Can you help me resolve the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that the .a you have are from a different version than the header files.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in case of static linking Open CV core library requires some 3-d party libraries. For example zlib